# How to seal hardwood floor in preparation of self-leveling compound?

Tags: hardwood-floor, subfloor, sealing, self-leveling-concrete

I'm planning to float laminate over my existing floor, but need to level it first. The floor area is very large, so it spans areas of the home that have differing subfloor materials: concrete, hardwood oak, and plywood. My plan is to use self-leveling compound across all the subfloor materials to make them consistent, level and flat. However, in order to pour the compound, I read the wood areas need to be sealed first with a primer.

Home Depot sells "LevelQuik Advanced Acrylic Primer" for sealing OSB or Exterior Grade Plywood, but this product does not work with hardwood flooring like oak; I confirmed this by calling the manufacturer.

At this point, I'm not sure how to seal my oak floor in order to pour self-leveling compound on top of it. Is it possible? I'd like to avoid ripping up the oak floor and replacing it with OSB or Exterior Grade Plywood, so it can then be sealed and leveled.

Comment: I guess I am not sure why you need to seal the now sub floor if there are no gaps self leveling compound will work in all 3 areas. If there are gaps a simple call will seal it  and the leveling will work great.

Comment: What is "call"?

Comment: The specification for the self-leveling compound (LevelQuik) I saw at Home Depot says it cannot be bonded directly to hardwood. Perhaps other leveling compounds are different? The specification for the product I referred to is at https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/67/67f33db6-86aa-4186-9c9a-50d4bb6cddef.pdf in case it's of interest.

Comment: Calking my phone has a crappy spell check and I don't always notice it has changed things.

Comment: wood needs sealing so the water dose not seep out of the leveling compound making it a differant blend than recomended

Answer (score -1):

I used a self leveling compound to level my bathroom floor. It trowels on and was recommended to go over linoleum. Stuck like glue but had to be sanded a little to level properly. I think it would work on hardwood as well. Sorry can’t remember the name but bought it at Lowe’s. I think it was m 50 something in a green can.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about sealing hardwood, and it seems to be a product recommendation, which is off topic.